# Error Parse JSON Response String Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, response

I have a response String from an API service like this :

```
{"id":"login","status":"true"}
```

and This is the way to parse Response String to get Value from Key "Status"

```
                    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
    try{
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();


    }


        JSONArray innerJsonArray = null;
        try {
            innerJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("status");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("status"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and I've got error 
"org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Anyone can give me suggestion?

Comment: use `getBoolean()` not `getJSONArray()`...

Comment: clearly error pointing you are trying to convert Jsonobject to JsonArray .because current string contain only jsonobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = null;
try{
    jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
    System.out.println(jsonObj.getString("status"));
}
catch(JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You do not need to bother with any other arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In which line you get the exception ? In any way may be you should use

`jsonObj =JSONObject.fromObject(responseString);`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try the snippet code below. Try this [link](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/) for gaining better knowledge about parsing an JSON response.

```
JSONObject jObj;
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
            Log.i("id==", jObj.getString("id"));
            Log.i("status==", jObj.getString("status"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```