# Android && JSON: Changing JSON Response Message to Plain Text

Tags: android, json

I get the **JSONResult** in android logcat in Json Encoded format well, I have to change the Json resoponse `message to simple plain text`  and show to the user in Edit Text Field.

The Response message which i get is some thing like that.

> 3{"success":0,"message":"Oops! Appointment Full"}

kindly help me out.

Comment: what is your question ? how to parse this JSON ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Parse JSON Response String Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661537/error-parse-json-response-string-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the string values of success message

```
JSONObject jObject new JSONObject(jString);// jString is your string response

int successValue = jObject.getInt("success");
String messageValue= jObject.getString("message");
// you can cast successValue to string
String successStringValue = String.valueOf(successValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Covert the response your are getting into a string for e.g 
`String result1 = responsemessage.toString();`

try this

`JSONObject someObject = new JSONObject(result1);`

```
JSONArray Jarray = Jarray.getInt("success");
```

`JSONArray Jarray = Jarray.getString("message");'`

coz you result you are getting is an json object and not json array

Comment: thanks for answer but give an exception **{"success":0,"message":"Oops! Appointment Full"} of type orgjson.jsonobject can not be converted to jArray**

Comment: getJSONArray is not applicable to String object...

Answer (score 0):

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourStringResponse);
    String message = json.getString("message");
    yourEditText.setText(message);
```